# Error while publishing react site to github.io

Tags: reactjs, github

I'm trying to publish my react site to github pages.(URL: https://kumarsreenivas051.github.io/kumar-site/ )

I'm committing the code directly to master branch in Github.

My package.json contains:

```
{
  "name": "kumar-site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap-validation": "^0.1.11",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "homepage": "https://kumarsreenivas051.github.io/kumar-site"
}
```

When I try to run `gh-pages -d build`

Getting errors. Log is showing:

```
14 verbose lifecycle kumar-site@0.1.0~deploy: CWD: C:\Users\Kumaraswamy V S\Documents\GitHub\kumarsreenivas051.github.io\kumar-site
15 silly lifecycle kumar-site@0.1.0~deploy: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'gh-pages -d build' ]
16 silly lifecycle kumar-site@0.1.0~deploy: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
17 info lifecycle kumar-site@0.1.0~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
18 verbose stack Error: kumar-site@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
19 verbose pkgid kumar-site@0.1.0
20 verbose cwd C:\Users\Kumaraswamy V S\Documents\GitHub\kumarsreenivas051.github.io\kumar-site
21 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
22 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "deploy"
23 verbose node v14.16.0
24 verbose npm  v6.14.11
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error kumar-site@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
27 error Exit status 1
28 error Failed at the kumar-site@0.1.0 deploy script.
28 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
29 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What can I do so that Site get's published successfully ?

FYI: OS used is Windows 10 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

I see only one branch in https://github.com/kumarsreenivas051/kumarsreenivas051.github.io

So for [`gh-pages` script](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#step-2-install-gh-pages-and-add-deploy-to-scripts-in-packagejson) to execute correctly, you might need to specify the branch.
Tweak your `package.json` scripts to push deployments to main:

```yaml
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
-   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
+   "deploy": "gh-pages -b main -d build",
```

Comment: That really worked out! In addition to that I didn't add git in environmental variables. So after all these changes I'm now able to view the site( https://kumarsreenivas051.github.io/ ) live.

Comment: @Kumar What is missing for you to unaccept this answer?